# Renaming of data series in excel chart via python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to rename dataseries in my charts, I tried different approaches on this code, but I am still unsuccesfull... I have header in table from which I am creating a charts and I expected to name the series as headers, but it takes first number on data series instead. Can you please help me? See code below:

```
chart1 = LineChart()
chart2 = LineChart()
chart3 = LineChart()

# Define the data range for x and y values
data1 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=12, min_row=2, max_col=12, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)  # Column 12 corresponds to "Time Elapsed"
values1 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=13, min_row=2, max_col=13, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)  # Column 13 corresponds to "Flux-mittel"
values2 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=14, min_row=2, max_col=14, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)  # Column 14 corresponds to "Flux-aktuell"
values3 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=9, min_row=2, max_col=9, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)   # Column 9 corresponds to "Volume Filtrate"
values4 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=10, min_row=2, max_col=10, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)  # Column 10 corresponds to "deltaP"
values5 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=11, min_row=2, max_col=11, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)  # Column 11 corresponds to "TMP"
values6 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=7, min_row=2, max_col=7, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)  # Column 7 corresponds to "Temperatur Filter"
values7 = Reference(new_sheet, min_col=8, min_row=2, max_col=8, max_row=new_sheet.max_row)  # Column 11 corresponds to "Turbidity Filter"

# Add data to the first chart
chart1.add_data(values1, titles_from_data=True)
chart1.add_data(values2, titles_from_data=True)
chart1.add_data(values3, titles_from_data=True)
chart1.set_categories(data1)

# Add data to the second chart
chart2.add_data(values4, titles_from_data=True)
chart2.add_data(values5, titles_from_data=True)
chart2.set_categories(data1)

#Add data to the third chart
chart3.add_data(values6, titles_from_data=True)
chart3.add_data(values7, titles_from_data=True)
chart3.set_categories(data1)

# Set the title for the charts and axes
chart1.title = "Vol/Flow Diagramm"
chart1.x_axis.title = "Time Elapsed"
chart1.y_axis.title = "Filtr. Vol. [hl], Flux mittel/aktuell [l/(m2h)]"

# Position the second chart to overlay the first one
chart2.title = "Pressure Diagramm"
chart2.x_axis.title = "Time Elapsed"
chart2.y_axis.title = "deltaP/TMP [mbar]"

# Position the third chart to overlay the second one
chart3.title = "Temperature/Turbidity Diagramm"
chart3.x_axis.title = "Time Elapsed"
chart3.y_axis.title = "Temperatur/Turbidity [°C/NTU]"

# Create a legend and specify the names for the data series
legend1 = chart1.legend
legend2 = chart2.legend
legend3 = chart3.legend
legend1.overlay = False  # Show the legend without overlaying the chart
legend2.overlay = False  # Show the legend without overlaying the chart
legend3.overlay = False  # Show the legend without overlaying the chart

# Set the size of the charts (width and height in EMU units)
chart1.width = 25  # Width: 15 inches in EMU (914400 EMU per inch)
chart1.height = 15  # Height: 10 inches in EMU
chart2.width = 25  # Width: 15 inches in EMU (914400 EMU per inch)
chart2.height = 15  # Height: 10 inches in EMU
chart3.width = 25  # Width: 15 inches in EMU (914400 EMU per inch)
chart3.height = 15  # Height: 10 inches in EMU

# Add the charts to a new sheet called "Charts"
chart_sheet = workbook.create_sheet("Charts")
chart_sheet.add_chart(chart1, "A1")  # Place the first chart in cell A1 of the "Charts" sheet
chart_sheet.add_chart(chart2, "A31")  # Place the second chart in cell A31 of the "Charts" sheet
chart_sheet.add_chart(chart3, "P1")  # Place the second chart in cell P1 of the "Charts" sheet

# Save the modified workbook
workbook.save(modified_file)

print("Line chart with legends added to the 'Charts' sheet.")
```

I tried to set titles_from_data=False, title = "X", but it didnt work. I also tried to set series names as chart.series[0].title = "X", but it also didnt work.

Comment: Row 1 has the names and Row 2 is the first row with data? So you have your Reference start on Row 2 and `titles_from_data=True` therefore the 'series name' section of your series will be taken from row 2. Change the `min_row=` to 1

Comment: Solved, thank you very much!